# appending two edgelist files based on column values

Tags: python, awk

I have two *edgelists*  such as:

File1

```
geneA geneB 0.89

geneA geneD 0.69

geneC geneA 0.76
```

File2

```
geneC geneF rank1

geneB geneA rank56

geneA geneC rank20
```

After comparing file1 and file2,

I should get:

```
geneA geneB 0.89 rank56

geneC geneA 0.76 rank20
```

since my graph is *undirected* and *geneA-geneB* is **same** as *geneB-geneA*.

I tried with python which is taking considerable time:

```
f=open('file1.txt', 'r')
f1=open('file2.txt','r')


for i in f.readlines():
    i=i.strip()
    gene_info=i.split()
    gene_info[0]=gene_info[0].strip()
    gene_info[1]=gene_info[1].strip()
    #print gene_info[0], gene_info[1]

for j in f1.readlines():
    i=i.strip()
    loc_info=i.split()
    loc_info[0]=loc_info[0].strip()
    loc_info[1]=loc_info[1].strip()
    if (gene_info[0]==loc_info[0] and gene_info[1]==loc_info[1])or (gene_info[0]==loc_info[1] and gene_info[1]==loc_info[0]):
        print j, '\t', gene_info[2]
```

Any quicker way is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to get a key that's independent of the order of it's component values is to sort them so no matter the order the values appear in the input they're always in the same order in the key:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = ($1 > $2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1) }
NR==FNR { a[key] = $3; next }
key in a { print $0, a[key] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
geneA geneB 0.89 rank56
geneC geneA 0.76 rank20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
       a[$1,$2]=$3;
       a[$2,$1]=$3;
       next
     }
     (($1,$2)in a){
        print $1,$2,a[$1,$2],$3
     }' file1 file2
```

The array `a` stores the decimal value for both combinations of the 2 indexes.

The main loop prints only the line when both indexes are in the array `a`.

Comment: That will use twice as much memory as necessary, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52930414/1745001

Comment: @EdMorton you're right (again)... I upvoted your answer!